# How do I parse children nodes?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar, ebnf

So lets say I have the following grammar:

```
let_stat = "let" iden [ "=" expr ];
if_stat = "if" expr "->" stat;
stat = let_stat | if_stat;
```

This would be the following psuedo-ish code:

```
let_stat parseLetStat() {


if token is "let" {
        consume token

        if token is identifier {
            char *value = consumetoken.value
            let_stat let = new let_stat;
            let.name = value;

            if token is "=" {
                let.value = parseExpression;
            }

            return let
        }
    }
}

if_stat parseIfStat() {
    if token is "if" {
        consume token

        expression expr = parseExpression;
        block block = parseBlock;

        if_stat ifstmt = new if_stat
        ifstmt.expr = expr
        ifstmt.block = block
        return ifstmt
    }
}

stat parseStatement() {

}
```

What would the `parseStatement` function do? How would it choose which function to call, the if_stat function, or the let_stat function? Or would I throw all the code into one function? I don't quite understand, any help would be great since I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key issue for your specific problem is that when there is alternation in an EBNF rule, the parser for the nonterminal must call *all* the alternatives and ask each if it recognizes the construct; each subparser has to return a flag indicating yes or no.

What you  probably need are [general principles for writing a recursive descent parser.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245962/is-there-an-alternative-for-flex-bison-that-is-usable-on-8-bit-embedded-systems/2336769#2336769)

Comment: Oh I see, perfect. And of course, answered from the one and only Ira Baxter, you seem to answer a lot of my questions :) Thanks! :)

Comment: @user3839220: You're asking questions on my turf :-}